# How to replace eggs in cake recipe and keep the cake from breaking?

Tags: substitutes, recipe-request, lacto-vegetarianism, egg-substitutes

I use Betty Crocker's Yellow cake mix. In the cake powder, as the recipe asks, I add about 1 cup of water, half cup of oil but to replace 3 eggs I add a pinch of baking powder and 1/3 cup of homemade greek yogurt.

After baking, the cake tastes really good, but when taking the cake out of the pan, the bottom layer of the cake usually sticks to the pan (even after butter/oil it and dust it with flour/cake powder). When taking a piece out of the cake, the cake doesn't stick together and starts breaking. Also, it does not rise as much as cakes with egg do.

I suspect that my egg alternatives do not really replace the cake, so what else can I use that will give the cake exactly what an egg provides?

Side note: I am fine with dairy products, but just not eggs.

Answer (score 6):

I find the best substitute to for eggs is [aquafaba](https://minimalistbaker.com/a-guide-to-aquafaba/) (the liquid in a can of chickpeas). You can also make it yourself if you cook chickpeas at home, just reduce the water you cooked them in until it's slimy like egg whites.

3 tbsp  of aquafaba = 1 egg.

I use it as a substitute for eggs everywhere. Baking, mayo, pancakes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

*TL;DR: use one tablespoon of flaxseed meal per egg as a drop in substitute for eggs in baking. To avoid clumping, soak the flaxseed meal in an equal volume of water first or add the flaxseed meal to the recipe last.*

[Eggs serve a few main purposes](https://pastrychefonline.com/2015/03/14/how-do-eggs-function-in-baking/) in baking, they:

- provide structure
- provide some leavening
- provide water, macronutrients, and flavor
- function as an emulsifier.

When the proteins in eggs are heated, they denature and bond to each other, and form a network. This is how eggs give baked goods structure, their protein network. Other food products that provide structure by forming polymer networks include gluten, pectin, and something in flaxseed (unfortunately, I'm not sure what exactly). Of those three, flaxseed gives a structure most similar to that of eggs, but it needs to cool back down before the structure fully forms.

When eggs are whipped, they form small bubble of air. When these bubbles are heated, they expand, which causes some expansion. The amount of leavening caused by eggs in most baking recipes however, is insignificant.

Eggs provide some liquid to recipes, which affects the consistency of the batter a little. Additionally, they provide some fats, which hinders gluten formation, and stops baked goods from becoming tough. In recipes without a source of fat besides eggs, some oil may need to be added.

Finally, eggs act as an emulsifier, which means they prevent mixtures of water and oil from separating. In most baked goods recipes, this doesn't matter, because batter will not separate anyway.

Because baking recipes usually rely on the structure provided by eggs much more than any of the other properties, flaxseed meal usually makes a good substitute for eggs in baking.

Comment: I used grinded flaxseeds before in backing cakes and it worked fine. However when using it for a different dish it didn't work at all - the dish was very slimey to the point that I couldn't eat it (I find the slimey consistency of flaxseeds submerged in water for a while or of actual egg white extremely gross). What am I doing wrong? I take 1.5 tablespoons mixed with 3 to 4 tablespoons of water per egg and it worked nicely for the cake. The dish didn't cool before eating compared to the cake, but I don't recall the cake to be slimey even when it was still hot.

Comment: @RimaNari What was the dish? You can't, for instance, use flaxseed to make scrambled “eggs”.

Comment: Thinking about it, it actually was a quite egg-heavy dish: "potato cake", basically potatoes grated very fine, mixed with an onion, eggs and some cheese, baked in the oven. It was 500 g potatoes on 3 eggs (1 egg is supposedly about 50 g), so I reckon it's a  rather egg-heavy dish. Maybe flaxseeds don't work here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a simpler recipe, 330 ml of a carbonate drink will replace oil, eggs, and milk.

Or you can use chia, flax, or cornflour as egg substitutes. It is 1 tablespoon of chia, flax, or cornflour mixed with 3 tablespoons of water. Flax and chia seed "eggs" need at least 10 minutes soaking in the water before they are ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you flax or chia egg (1 tablespoon flax/chia amd 3 tablespoon of water), I recommend adding 1/2 teaspoon of bicarbonate of soda/baking soda to help it rise more and be fluffy. Another option is using 1 tablespoon of cornflour/corn starch to 3 tablespoons of water.

I haven't tested aquafaba. The 330 ml of soda works well.